# Not able to debug this jQuery

Tags: jquery, debugging

If you look at my sandbox site [englishgodsandbox](http://englishgod.com), after about 8 seconds, a drop down menu with a button "confirm" loads in the middle of the page. If you click the "confirm" button, the background image for the page should change according to the last few lines of code below.

However, the image is not changing...Can anyone tell me why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(init);   
}); 

function init() {
    cloudshow();
}
function cloudshow() {
    $("#intro").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $("#intro2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $("#cloud1").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                $("#cloud2, #cloud5").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                    $("#cloud3, #cloud4, #cloud6").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                        $("#message").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                            $("#contactform").fadeIn(1000)
                        });  
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
};



var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/map.jpg') repeat";

$(".submit").click(function(){
    $("body.custom").css({background: img1});
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `$` in this line: `$(init);` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I got that code from a tutorial.

Comment: If you pass a function to the jQuery function, it is equivalent to `$(document).ready(...)`, so you could change that line to `init();` or, remove the `$(document).ready` call altogether.

Comment: Thanks. are you suggesting that might be the source of my problem, or is just a general best practice?

Comment: Just general best practice, sorry (hence the comment instead of an answer). :)

Comment: `$(init);` sets a function reference to the document.ready event like: `$(function() { init(); });` which is `$(document).ready(function() { init(); });`

Comment: @nickf, ha ha, I will give you many three sided coins if you can figure this one out. I have a clue about the problem but can't fix it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608809/drag-and-drop-works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-on-my-site-but-i-have-one-clue

Comment: @Michael: When using code from a tutorial, try to understand each line. Don't just copy/paste it into your webpage. You said you're not sure what `$(init)` does, which indicates you weren't yet ready to use the code! (Although, as nickf explained, it's poor code.)

Comment: @Tomalak, I understand the purpose of init generally, but as for the choice of syntax, I don't know the nuances of every dollar sign etc because I'm still learning

Comment: @Michael: OK, and what I mean is that you should find out! You can't debug your code unless you know what it's _supposed_ to be doing.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal yes, i agree, understanding is necessary to debug, but to really really really understand, you also have to know what's happening underneath the jquery in the javascript. I have even read books on javascript but it's still all jumbled up in my brain...

Comment: @Michael: Hmm, no, you just need to [look up `$` in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: well, yes, I know what the $ does generally, but at the same time if it's used incorrectly, I might not always notice, especially if I see a tutorial with working code. I'm not experienced enough to say, "well, the code works, but it's better if it can be written this way..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reference the `$(".submit")` elemets before they are parsed into the DOM. Putting them in a reday event, or at the end of body would solve your problem.

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        $("body.custom").css({background: img1});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I see the problem.

At the time that the last three lines there are executed, the `.submit` button isn't actually on the page yet.

Move those lines into your `init()` function and give that a try.

The init function is only being executed after the document is ready, therefore the button should be there at that time.

Comment: thank you. 3 people answered, so I have to flip a coin to see who gets accepted answer. You lost. sorry, but thank you so much.

Comment: @Michael -- I want one of your three-sided coins

Answer (score 1):

In order to

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    $("body.custom").css({background: img1});
});
```

work you should ensure that $(".submit") exists, so try:

```
var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/map.jpg') repeat";

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  init();   

  $(".submit").click(function(){
        $("body.custom").css({background: img1});
  });

});
```

Comment: thank you. 3 people answered, so I have to flip a coin to see who gets accepted answer. You lost. sorry, but thank you so much.